# IRI: Find neighbor which uses the testnet

Tags: iri-node, iota-network, neighbors, testnet

I see really often the following message in the logs:

> Transaction resolves to incorrect ledger balance: -8727317092450

I checked my version. It is the main net. But I guess I got a neighbor who is not on the main net. I also had trouble with other neighbors because of the old 1.4.1.2 version.

So my question is: How do I check which neighbor is not on the main net?

Answer (score 1):

check this out:

```
String name = instance.configuration.booling(Configuration.DefaultConfSettings.TESTNET) ? IRI.TESTNET_NAME : IRI.MAINNET_NAME;
                    return GetNodeInfoResponse.create(name, IRI.VERSION,
```

from

> src/main/java/com/iota/iri/service/API.java

i.e. if you are looking at a list of nodes with their getNodeInfo data you might see: https://gist.github.com/andrewarrow/6d1eacc538ee973af77f399586767fd5

getNodeInfo is available via:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-IOTA-API-Version: 1" -d '{"command": "getNodeInfo"}' http://176.9.3.149:14265
```